# translate jQuery to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, language-translation

I have to fix some form validation but there's no jQuery included in the host page. I'd normally do something like this...

```
if ($("#contactNameAdd").val() !== '' || $("#contactPhoneAdd").val() !== '') {
    $("#contactForm").show()
};
```

How can I re-write that in normal js?

Comment: Its almost as if jQuery makes people lazy ... this is very simple ... any JavaScript developer should really know this kind of stuff ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = document.getElementById("contactNameAdd");
var phone = document.getElementById("contactPhoneAdd");
var form = document.getElementById("contactForm");

if(name.value != '' || phone.value != '') {
   form.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.getElementById('contactNameAdd').value !== '' || document.getElementById('contactPhoneAdd').value !== '') {
    document.getElementById('contactForm').style.display = 'block';
}
```

In plain javascript, you use [document.getElementById('id')](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#method-getElementById) to get DOM nodes based on the id attribute. You use `.value` on a DOM Input element to get its value. And you use `.style` on any DOM element to set css attributes. In this case "show" means "display: block;".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElemenById('contactNameAdd').value != '' || document.getElementById('contactPhoneAdd').value != '') {
    document.getElementById('contactForm').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Try this - checks the 2 values then changes the style.display property of the 'contactForm'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var contactNameAdd = document.getElementById("contactNameAdd");
var contactPhoneAdd = document.getElementById("contactPhoneAdd");

if((contactNameAdd !== null && contactNameAdd.value !== '') || (contactPhoneAdd !== null && contactPhoneAdd.value !== ''))
{
    document.getElementById("contactForm").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: getElementById <- lowercase 'g'

Comment: Thanks ManselUK, didn't notice my typo at the top.

Comment: i didnt want to edit you post - thought it was a bit cheeky !

Answer (score 0):

```
var contactName = document.getElementById('contactNameAdd');
var contactPhone = document.getElementById('contactPhoneAdd');
if(contactName.value !== '' || contactPhone.value !== '') {
  // Different as JQuery, there will be no animation.
  // I assume you use 'display:none' to hide the form.
  var form = document.getElementById('contactForm');
  form.style.display = 'block';
}
```